# Not able to decode JSON data in Flex

Tags: arrays, json, apache-flex

I'm new to Flex. I'm trying to populate JSON data into Datagrid using the below code. But I failed to decode JSON Data. I have added as3corelib.swc in my flex Project. I was trying to populate JSON data from java backend and it failed with below mentioned error (given at End of page). So trying this simple example to know JSON decoder works or not. I have referred lot of internet sources and it seems the below code is valid.

Seeking for your valuable guidance on this.

```
private function applicationCompleteHandler():void
{
    var channel:AMFChannel = new AMFChannel("my-amf", "hxxp://localhost:8400/springapp/messagebroker/amf");
    var channelSet:ChannelSet = new ChannelSet();
    channelSet.addChannel(channel);
    po.channelSet = channelSet;
    //po.findAll();

    var httpService:HTTPService=new HTTPService();
    httpService.resultFormat="text";
    httpService.url="http://date.jsontest.com/?service=ip"
    httpService.method=HTTPRequestMessage.POST_METHOD;
    httpService.contentType="application/json";
    httpService.send();
    httpService.addEventListener(ResultEvent.RESULT, onJSONLoad);
}

private function onJSONLoad(event:ResultEvent):void
{
    var rawData:String=String(event.result);
    var arr:Array=(com.adobe.serialization.json.JSON.decode(rawData) as Array);
    var dp:ArrayCollection=new ArrayCollection(arr);
    dg.dataProvider=dp;

}
```

---

```
JSONParseError: Unexpected o encountered
at com.adobe.serialization.json::JSONTokenizer/parseError()
at com.adobe.serialization.json::JSONTokenizer/getNextToken()
at com.adobe.serialization.json::JSONDecoder/nextToken()
at com.adobe.serialization.json::JSONDecoder/parseArray()
at com.adobe.serialization.json::JSONDecoder/parseValue()
at com.adobe.serialization.json::JSONDecoder()
at com.adobe.serialization.json::JSON$/decode()
at ProductService/po_resultHandler()
at ProductService/__po_result()
at flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEventFunction()
at flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEvent()
at mx.rpc::AbstractService/dispatchEvent()
at mx.rpc.remoting.mxml::RemoteObject/dispatchEvent()
at mx.rpc::AbstractOperation/http://www.adobe.com/2006/flex/mx/internal::dispatchRpcEvent()
at mx.rpc::AbstractInvoker/http://www.adobe.com/2006/flex/mx/internal::resultHandler()
at mx.rpc::Responder/result()
at mx.rpc::AsyncRequest/acknowledge()
at NetConnectionMessageResponder/resultHandler()
at mx.messaging::MessageResponder/result()
```

Comment: Could you post the contents of the `rawData` variable from the line before you call JSON.decode?

Comment: Thanks Brian. rawData contains [rawData = "{"ip": "129.178.182.9"}
"] and arr variable holds null.

Comment: According to jsonlint.com, `{"ip":"129.178.182.9"}` is valid JSON, but `"{"ip":"129.178.182.9"}"` and `[rawData = "{"ip": "129.178.182.9"} "]` are not.  You probably have to trim the rawData string to make sure it's valid JSON before passing it to the decoder.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using array use object as per shown below

```
private function onJSONLoad(event:ResultEvent):void
{
   var jsonObj:Object= com.adobe.serialization.json.JSON.decode(urlLoader.data);
   trace(jsonObj.forecastList[0].dayDesc);              

}
```

I have a different json format so use your json format to tarce the object or else show me your json format or URL.

Instead of using httpservice if you have no problem then use urlRequest and urlLoader it would be better.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Subrat & Brian.

I think the issue was with JSON input format. Java is sending the JSON data in object structure. So I found a website which provides Sample JSON data. Then while debugging I found that the Website shares data in plain text which looks totally different from what my java back end sends. The code is as below.

```
private function onJSONLoad(event:ResultEvent):void
```

{

```
var jsonObj:Object = (JSON.parse(event.result.toString()));
var arr:ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection(jsonObj.heroes as Array);
var arrobj:ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection(jsonObj as Array);
this.dg.dataProvider = new ArrayCollection(jsonObj.heroes as Array);
```

}

```
<s:HTTPService id="httpService" 
url="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kronusme/dota2-api/master/data/heroes.json"
resultFormat="text" method="POST" useProxy="false" result="onJSONLoad(event)"/>
```

Though I had some issues with crossdomain in running this code, I was able to debug this code and data got filled in my datagrid as expected.

So I might try to fix the format sending from my Java backend to UI.

I am using net.sf.json in backend to create JSONArray. If this does not work, I will use RemoteObject in Flex and manage to fill my datagrid :(

Once again Thanks Guys.